# Is there a better way to horizontally align elements, than text-align: centre?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I have a div, I need ALL the elements inside to be centred, this includes; text and some images.

```
.class {
    text-align: centre;
}
```

Works, however is there a better (best practice) Way to do this? I tried fiddling with margins etc... and it worked up until I resized to browser windows, any images that moved down (next row) were automatically aligned left?

What I am asking is there a css class similar to `vertical-align` but for aligning elements horizontally?

Comment: there are ways, but none better than this. Furthermore, most techniques will require `text-align:center` at some point. This is exactly what this property is made for. I don't understand why are you looking for something else, though, so not sure if I'm getting your question

Comment: I am looking for a property for aligning elements like images to the center not just text.

Comment: Show at least an example (with *valid* HTML and CSS) of what you have tried and explain what you expect to happen and how that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-align: center` (**not centre**) is your best bet. There are things you can do to prevent the items from breaking to a new line, such as setting a (max-)width on images inside this div based on media queries. But as far as aligning them in the center goes, just use `text-align` and if you want to break to a new line, a simple `br` will do the trick.

You said you played with margins. If you want to space elements out on the same row, keep using the `margin` property, but *in addition to* the `text-align` on the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You may use margin to horizontally align

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/knzg410f/

Answer (score 0):

alternate way : 
to align horizontally you could use paragraph tag:

```
<p align="center">your text here</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lz59zca/